# Basic SELECT fails to find entry

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I'm probably making a stupid beginner mistake here but SQL isn't one of my strong points.

I'm trying to modify a simple SQLite DB (in SQLite Manager) but can't seem to do it until I figure out why I can't get this select statement to return.

```
SELECT *
FROM facts
WHERE id = -9215979828305747000
```

threw no error and returned nothing regardless of the fact that its the first entry on the table. I also tried

```
SELECT *
FROM facts
WHERE CAST(facts.id AS INTEGER) = CAST('-9215979828305747000' AS INTEGER)
```

again nothing.

I see the value in the browse window but can't get it in a specific search. Is this happening because of value length?

Comment: do you have any record with this negative value of ID ? what is data type of your ID field?

Comment: What result do you get if you run `select min(id) from facts` ?

Comment: ID is type Integer according to the CREATE TABLE.
min(id) returns "-9215979828305747000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this test :

```
CREATE TABLE "test" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT
)

insert into test values (1, "tttt")
insert into test values (-9215979828305747000, "OO")


select name from test where id = -9215979828305747000'

> "OO"
```

So it seems to work in a fresh new table. The problem is clearly not in the sql select or key or table definition.

Try to get the data in some temporary table :

```
insert into table_copy values (select * from facts)
```

Comment: When I made a temporary table in the db and filled it with the values I needed from the facts table, I still couldn't get the SELECT statement to work. However when I tried manually doing your example it worked. So I tried something different. I made a "variable" entry in a table meant to hold dynamically changing data and used the min(id) to fill the value. I then referenced back to it: `select * from facts where id = ( select value from deckVars where key = 'temp' )` and SUCCESS, the SELECT worked. I'm not sure why this works but the other doesn't. Must still be casting issue somewhere.

Comment: I see the problem. `UPDATE deckVars SET temp = ( select min(id) from test ) where key = 'temp'` fills it with a different number than what I see by verifying in SQLite Manager. IN ADDITION, `select min(id) from test` also returns the value I see in the Manager but not the value I get in Update. Its the value that I get when I execute the Update that actually works when I use the value in temp. Not quite sure whats going on here.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot see how to help you further. Try to bloc-copy all the valid data in a fresh new table, backup the database and try some deletes (on a copy somewhere ?) - I also noticed two different INT in SQLite when creating table : INT as primary key and INT. Is there a difference between the two ?

Comment: I have no idea. Having discovered how to access the table though and get a valid SELECT, I think I'll just have to write a small script in python to do what I need. Thanks for the help (everyone)!

Comment: If you wanna thank for the help, please upvote the helpful answers (or all) and accept one ! This will not cost you.

Answer (score 1):

-9215979828305747000 is bigger than the maximum value for an Int32 (2147483647), so I guess facts.id is not an Integer. Check your datatype and CAST accordingly.

Perhaps it is a string?

```
SELECT *
FROM facts
WHERE id = '-9215979828305747000'
```

Comment: Nope its defiantly an integer, or at least that is how the table was created.
`CREATE TABLE facts (
 id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 "modelId" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 created FLOAT NOT NULL, 
 modified FLOAT NOT NULL, 
 tags TEXT NOT NULL, 
 "spaceUntil" TEXT NOT NULL, 
 "lastCardId" INTEGER, 
 PRIMARY KEY (id), 
 FOREIGN KEY("modelId") REFERENCES models (id)
)`

Edit: But if its larger than the max value, that probably explains why I can't get it as an integer OR a string. Hmm.

Comment: What if you try to cast the other way around. Cast id as string and then compare to the string '-9215979828305747000'.
I don't understand why you can get such a big (or small) number in an Int.

Comment: I can't get it as a string either: `SELECT * FROM facts WHERE CAST(facts.id AS STRING) = CAST('#' AS STRING)` . That large number would fit in a BIGINT right? A bit of googling shows another question where someone mentioned that SQLite apprently holds whatever you put in an 'integer' type, from 1-byte to 8-byte. I already tried casting as BIGINT too, no luck.